# Baking onto a 'project from view' UV

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I am modifying a building in a game (Empire Earth if you're interested). The model is fully 3D (image 1), but the texture is an isometric drawing (image 2).

I would like to bake shadows (generated by the surrounding objects and by itself) onto the ground (image 3).

Because my texture is isometric, I had to project the UV from view, so panels at the back overlap those in front on the UV map. This causes discontinuities to appear where is has double baked the same area (image 4).

Is there a way to have an output UV map that is different to the input UV map? Ideally my bake output would be unwrapped (image 5).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can define the UVMaps with the UVMap node in the Shader editor.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do this is as follows:

1: Make a new **UV Map** in Object Data Properties < UV Maps (make sure to select it).
[image]

2: Make a new **image** in the UV editor.
[image]

3: Arrange the new UV in the new **image** how you want it to be.
[image]

4: Add a UV Map node to the Shader Editor; connect it to the image texture node (mine is called 'Bake'); select the new **UV Map** (mine is called 'model-bake'). Select the new **image** in the image texture node (also called 'Bake').
[image]

5: Bake!